# Apache Airflow: Clean a task with a config

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

I'm using Apache Airflow 2, I can re-run the whole dag using a config:

[image]

However sometimes I want to re-run only one task and not the whole dag with a config also, for now I can clear the task, but I'm not able to add a config, the task I want to clear with a config is in the red box:

[image]

Is it possible to do this with airflow, and if not is there's a workaround ?

Comment: This is a bit dirty, but you can rerun the dag w/ config, and then set the other not wanted tasks to success and keep only the tasks you want to run with the config.